# PHP 403 Forbidden While Posting HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, post, litespeed

I'm using a PHP code to insert content to MySQL database.

I use tinyMCE editor for content editing.

**The problem is, when I use some HTML tags in content, server sends me 403 - Forbidden
But if I get rid of HTML tags; I can insert my content, read it, edit it, delete it without any problem.**

What can I do?

I've tried changing characters like "<", ">", "=" etc to some other things like "aaaaa", "bbbbbbb" with str_replace. It works on local. It writes data to database like this and converts easily while reading.

I've tried base64_encode and decode too. This also worked on local.

But in server, none of them worked. So I thought the problem is not about inserting. It's about posting. Becaue I can't even echo my sql query or post value. As soon as I click submit, I see 403.

What do you suggest?

I've heard somebody saying

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

but it's not secure. If I add this lines to my htaccess, everything works fine.

Do you think I can modify this code for more security, or do I have to do something with my PHP script?

So you've asked about my PHP code. Here it is:

```
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
    //Diğer parametreleri de al:
    $_POST['icerik'] =  mysqli_real_escape_string($myDatabaseLink, $_POST['icerik']);
    //SQL sorgusunu hazırla:
    $sorgu =sprintf("INSERT INTO table VALUES('%s')", $_POST['icerik']);
    echo $_POST['icerik']; //Can't even reach here while posting HTML (otherwise no problem)
    echo $sorgu; 
    exit;
}
```

And the form layout. They both on the same page BTW:

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="blabla">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>İçerik:</td>
    <td><textarea name="icerik" id="editor1" class="ckeditor" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="add" value="Yazı Ekle"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: So, your POST request is being blocked by mod_security? You need to check your server error log to see which rule is being triggered, and then you need to figure out whether you can simply turn that rule off for this POST request, or whether you can change the request not to trigger that rule.

Comment: Did you see that htaccess block in question? You think using it is a good idea or I've to find another way?

Answer (score 0):

On this page you can find more about mod_security and what options you have to deal with the problem - http://wiki.modxcms.com/index.php/What_is_mod_security_and_how_does_it_affect_me